# Python print in gdb

Tags: python, printing, gdb

I want to add a simple  python command to gdb , but the command "print" is seen as an error inside gdb when invoking the python source . Any help ? thank you
My code is the following :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gdb
import re
import sys

class PrintGList(gdb.Command):
    """Visualise pointers and values in a given space  """

    def __init__(self):
        gdb.Command.__init__(self, "fpointers", gdb.COMMAND_DATA, gdb.COMPLETE_SYMBOL, True)

    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        arg_list = gdb.string_to_argv(arg)
        if len(arg_list) < 2:
            print "usage: fpointers <address> <offset>"
            return
        address = gdb.parse_and_eval(arg_list[0])
        offset = gdb.parse_and_eval(arg_list[1])

        print "address : "+str(address)+", offset : "+str(offset)

PrintGList()
```

Comment: Are you running python2.x or python3.x?

Comment: What is the error exactly? Is it possible that gdb is executing the Script with Python 3.x? Because then it has to be `print('...')`

Comment: I am running python 2.7

Comment: It seems that gdb doesn't recognize python's print

Comment: gdb doesn't touch that.  Most likely your gdb was linked against python 3.

Comment: I managed to use gdb.write() to print from python to the standard output